# How can I add Liferay's CKEditor to my JSF portlet?

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I want to add Liferay's CKEditor to my JSF portlet. I tried to find a way to add the CKEditor in JSF, but all the examples/solutions show how to add the CKEditor in a JSP not JSF.

I am using Liferay Portal 6.0 EE.

Comment: you can add primefaces extensions http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: @Daniel According to my opinion, if I already have CKEditor in Liferay why should I add primefaces extensions just for getting another CKEditor

Comment: Well if you already have it and can access in your JSF pages , just read some tutorials/example the same way you use it on JSP will work for you in JSF, I thought you wan't to use some ready made JSF component...

Comment: @Daniel https://www.liferay.com/web/erik.andersson/blog/-/blogs/rich-text-editor-in-custom-portlet I found this blog. But this is for jsp not for jsf.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the CKEditor to a JSF page by including the [Liferay Faces Portal jar](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/portal)* in your project, and writing code similar to one of the following examples:

**Liferay 6.2+ Example:**

```
<portal:inputRichText value="#{backing.value}" />
```

Check out the [Liferay Faces Showcase](http://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/showcase/-/component/portal/inputrichtext/general) for live examples and more details.

**Deprecated Liferay 6.2 and 6.1 Example:**

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor editorImpl="editor.wysiwyg.default" value="#{backing.value}">
```

**Deprecated Liferay 6.0 EE Example:**

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor editorImpl="ckeditor" value="#{backing.value}">
```

<sup>*Since you are using Liferay 6.0 EE, you need to use LF Portal version [`3.0.5-ga6`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/faces/liferay-faces-portal/3.0.5-ga6/). Consult the the [Liferay Faces Version Scheme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/understanding-the-liferay-faces-version-scheme) for more information on compatible Liferay Faces and Liferay Portal versions.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. Reference [Liferay Faces Showcase](http://www.liferayfaces.org/web/guest/showcase/-/component/portal/inputrichtext/general)

inputRichText.xhtml

```
<alloy:outputStylesheet library="css" name="input-rich-text.css" />
<alloy:form id="exampleForm">
    <alloy:field id="commentsField" label="#{i18n['comments']}" styleClass="input-rich-text-field">
        <alloy:message id="commentsMessage" for="comments" />
    </alloy:field>
    <!-- Note: In this example, portal:inputRichText is intentionally not a child of alloy:field in order -->
    <!-- to prevent it from being unnecessarily reinitialized when the alloy:field is re-rendered via Ajax. -->
    <portal:inputRichText id="comments" label="#{i18n['comments']}"
        required="#{showcaseModelBean.selectedComponent.required}"
        value="#{inputRichTextBacking.applicant.comments}" />
    <alloy:commandButton actionListener="#{inputRichTextBacking.submit}"
        render=":exampleForm:commentsField :modelValue" value="#{i18n['submit']}" />
</alloy:form>
<alloy:outputText id="modelValue" value="#{inputRichTextBacking.applicant.comments}" />
```

InputRichTextBacking.java

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class InputRichTextBacking {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InputRichTextBacking.class);

    private Applicant applicant;
    private boolean resizable = true;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        applicant = new Applicant();

        if (ViewParamUtil.getUsage().equals("default-value")) {
            applicant.setComments(
                "<p>This is some <strong>bold</strong> text\nand this is some <em>italic</em> text.</p>");
        }
    }

    public void submit() {
        logger.info("You entered comments: " + applicant.getComments());
    }

    public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        PhaseId phaseId = facesContext.getCurrentPhaseId();
        logger.debug("valueChangeListener: phaseId=[{0}]", phaseId.toString());

        String phaseName = phaseId.getName();
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("The valueChangeListener method was called during the " +
                phaseName + " phase of the JSF lifecycle.");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    }

    public Applicant getApplicant() {
        return applicant;
    }

    public boolean isResizable() {
        return resizable;
    }

    public void setResizable(boolean resizable) {
        this.resizable = resizable;
    }
}
```

Applicant.java

```
public class Applicant implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4661552363081858711L;

    private String city;
    private String comments;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String postalCode;
    private Long provinceId;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Long getProvinceId() {
        return provinceId;
    }

    public void setProvinceId(Long provinceId) {
        this.provinceId = provinceId;
    }
}
```

input-rich-text.css

```
/* The Liferay Portal margin-bottom is 30px for div elements with class="control-group" (such as alloy:field). */
/* Set the margin-bottom to zero since the portal:inputRichText is not a child of the alloy:field component tag. */ 
.aui div.input-rich-text-field.control-group {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.aui div.portal-input-rich-text {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

input-rich-text.properties

```
#
# The default key used by the editorImpl attribute is found in the Liferay portal.properties file:
#
#     editor.wysiwyg.default=ckeditor
#
# For more information, see:
#
#     https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L5282
#
# Alternate keys for BBCode and Creole can be specified in a custom portal-ext.properties file.
#
# For example:
#
com.liferay.faces.demos.showcase.ckeditor=ckeditor
com.liferay.faces.demos.showcase.ckeditor_bbcode=ckeditor_bbcode
com.liferay.faces.demos.showcase.ckeditor_creole=ckeditor_creole
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
<aui:fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
        }
    </script>
    <aui:field-wrapper label="content">
        <liferay-ui:input-editor width="100%" />
        <aui:input name="content" type="hidden" />
    </aui:field-wrapper>
</aui:fieldset>
```